# How To Grow Div Height Top Side

Tags: html, css

My problem Is I Want To Grow My Div Height Top Side With Out Using Position:absolute;
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .StartMenu{}
    </style>
</head>
      <body>
            <div class="StartMenu">
                <div class="item" ></div>
            </div>

      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can set margin-top:100px;

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like:

```css
.StartMenu{
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="StartMenu">
                <div class="item" ></div>
            </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Depending on how the OP wants the behavior, they might also need to use the style attribute position: relative; to keep the top from being hidden by its parent.

Answer (score 1):

On the other way, `padding-top` can do what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/a8ff1fg8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
padding:100px 0 0 0;
```

or

```
margin:100px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use padding if you want space inside Div.
use margin if you want your div to be moved.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .mydiv{
          padding-top:30px; // all elements inside div will move 30px down.
          margin-top:20px; // your div will move 20px down from parent tag.
      }
</style>
</head>
  <body>
        <div class="mydiv">
            <div class="item" ></div>
        </div>

  </body>
```